# merge 3 subscription data to join the data in new object rxjs angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova

i need some help to merge the data from 3 different sensor in one object, im using some cordova-plugins to get the acc gyr and mag data, but the problem i cant solve is to subscribe to all the 3 observables at the same time and get the data together into the same object, i tried to recursive call the observables but it doesnt work, this are my functions:

```html
startGyroscope(){
  this.gyroscopeSerie = [];
  this.subscriptionGyro = this.gyr.watch({frequency : 75}).subscribe(
     (magnetometer: any) => {
       let data = {
         x: 0,
         z: 0,
         y: 0,
         timestamp: 0
       };
       data.x = magnetometer.x;
       data.y = magnetometer.y;
       data.z = magnetometer.z;
       data.timestamp = + new Date(),
       this.gyroscopeSerie.push(data);
     }
   );
 }

startMagnetometer(){
  this.magnometerSerie = [];
 this.subscriptionMag = this.mag.watchReadings().subscribe(
    (magnetometer: any) => {
      let data = {
        x: 0,
        z: 0,
        y: 0,
        timestamp: 0,
        magnitude: 0
      };
      data.x = magnetometer.x;
      data.y = magnetometer.y;
      data.z = magnetometer.z;
      data.timestamp = + new Date(),
      data. magnitude = magnetometer.magnitude
      this.magnometerSerie.push(data);
    }
  );
}



startAccelerometer(){
  this.accelerometerSerie = [];
  const frequency =  75;
  this.watchID = setInterval(() =>{
    this.watchAcceleration().then((accelerometer: any) =>{
      let data = {
        x: 0,
        z: 0,
        y: 0,
        timestamp: 0,
        roll: 0,
        pitch: 0,
        yaw: 0
      };
      data.x = accelerometer.x;
      data.y = accelerometer.y;
      data.z = accelerometer.z;
      data.roll = accelerometer.roll;
      data.pitch = accelerometer.pitch;
      data.yaw = accelerometer.yaw;
      data.timestamp = accelerometer.timestamp;
      this.accelerometerSerie.push(data);
    });
  },frequency);
}
// this plugin doesnt have an wrapper so i had to create a promise callback
watchAcceleration(){
  return new Promise((resolveCallback, rejectCallback) =>{
   new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(resolve,reject,{frequency : 75});
   }).then((acceleration) => {
      resolveCallback(acceleration);
   }).catch((error) =>{
     rejectCallback(error);
   });
  });
}
```

expected output of all the values in this object:

```html
{ magx: 0 , magy: 0, magz: 0, accx: 0, accy: 0, accz: 0, roll: 0, pitch: 0, yaw: 0, girx: 0, giry: 0, girz: 0, timestamp: 0 };
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I’m understanding you correctly each of these observable emit in approximately the same intervals and should be about the same time. You want to only have the new combined object after all three observable have emitted there mew values and have been combined.  To do this I would mix combine latest and distinctUntilChanged like this. (Please excuse typos as this is done on my phone)

```
gyrData: Observable <any>
magData: Observable <any>
accelData = new Subject<any>();
combined: Observable<any
combinedSub;

initCombinedData() {
   this.startGyroscope();
   this. startMagnetometer();
   this.startAccelerometer();
   this.combined = combineLatest([
      this.gyrData,
      this.magData,
      this.accelData
   ])
   .pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged((a, b) =>
        // emit only when all time stamps have update to avoid any lag in updates and ensure they stay in sync
         a[0].timestamp === b[0].timestamp ||
         a[1].timestamp === b[1].timestamp ||
         a[2].timestamp === b[2].timestamp ||
       ),
       map(([gyr, mag, acc]) => {
           const latestTime = Math.max(
              gyr.timestamp,
              mag.timestamp,
              acc.timestamp)
           
           return { magx: mag.x, magy: mag.y, magz: mag.z, accx: acc.x, accy: acc.y, accz: acc.z, roll: acc.roll, pitch: acc.pitch, yaw: acc.yaw, girx: gyr.x, giry: gyr.y, girz: gyr.z, timestamp: new Date(latestTime) };
       })
    )
    this.combinedSub = this.combined.subscribe();
}

startGyroscope(){
  this.gyrData = this.gyr.watch({frequency : 75})
  .pipe(
     map((magnetometer: any) => {
       const data = {
         x: magnetometer.x,
         z: magnetometer.z,
         y: magnetometer.y,
        timestamp: + new Date()
       };
       return data;
    })
 }

startMagnetometer(){
 this.magData = this.mag.watchReadings()
    .pipe(
       map((m: any) => {
         const data = {
           x: m.x,
           z: m.z,
           y: m.y,
          timestamp: + new Date(),
          magnitude: m. magnitude
         };
         return data;
       }
      );
    }

 startAccelerometer(){
   const frequency =  75;
   this.watchID = setInterval(() =>{
   this.watchAcceleration()
      .then((a: any) =>{
        const data = {
           x: a.x,
           z: a.z,
           y: a.y,
           timestamp: a.timestamp,
           roll: a.roll,
           pitch: a.pitch
           yaw: a.yaw,
         };
        this.accelData.next(data);
     });
   },frequency);
 }

 watchAcceleration(){
    return new Promise((resolveCallback, rejectCallback) =>{
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
       navigator.accelerometer
          .watchAcceleration(resolve,reject, {frequency : 75});
      }).then((acceleration) => {
         resolveCallback(acceleration);
      }).catch((error) =>{
         rejectCallback(error);
    });
 });
}
```